# Expand Android quick setting on tap

Tags: android

I implemented a quick setting for Android N. Everything is working.

Now I want to add functionality like the WiFi quick setting. Tap on WiFi icon shows a list of available devices. In my setting on tap I wish to show radio buttons.

Could not find any help on developer.android.com

Is this even possible?

Comment: can you share the the quick settings code . It will give a head start to solve the problem

Comment: https://medium.com/google-developers/quick-settings-tiles-e3c22daf93a8 go through this it should answer your question

Comment: Thank you @AyushBansal . I found the answer. From the link it is clear that for 3rd party tiles it is not possible.